# 'ENV' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, mocha.js, dbmigrate

I am trying to switch my environment on testing and migrate to a new database when running my test cases but I am getting the following error. I am using docker compose to build the image

```
'ENV' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

I have a .env file with different values in it.

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "storefront_backend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc --build",
    "start": "tsc --build && ts-node src/server.ts",
    "watch": "tsc-watch --esModuleInterop src/server.ts --outDir ./dist --onSuccess \"node ./dist/server.js\"",
    "test": "ENV=test && npx tsc && db-migrate --env test up && mocha ./src/spec/*.js && db-migrate db:drop test",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "lint": "eslint --fix --ext .ts ."
  },
  "author": "Udacity",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "db-migrate": "^0.11.13",
    "db-migrate-pg": "^1.2.2",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "pg": "^8.5.1",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "^4.3.1",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.9",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.10.6",
    "@types/mocha": "^9.1.1",
    "@types/node": "^17.0.35",
    "@types/pg": "^7.14.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.26.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.26.0",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "chai": "^4.3.6",
    "chai-http": "^4.3.0",
    "eslint": "^8.16.0",
    "jasmine": "^3.6.4",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-ts": "^0.3.0",
    "jest": "^28.1.0",
    "mocha": "^10.0.0",
    "request": "^2.88.2",
    "supertest": "^6.2.3",
    "ts-node": "^9.1.1",
    "tsc-watch": "^4.2.9"
  }
}
```

Comment: Try Changing it to set ENV=test

Comment: What OS are you running on? This should work on Unixen: Linux, MacOS, Solaris, WSL, gitbash etc. The `variable=value command` syntax is Bourne shell syntax that is supported on most Unix shells

Comment: windows 11 is the os i am using